# Proper Syntax for printing obective array value from another array

Tags: php

When we have associative array values we can echo something this way

```
<?php
echo $arr1[$arr2[1]];
?>
```

What will be the correct syntax for Objective array? I tried this and it is not working

```
<?php
echo $arr1->{{$arr2[1]}}; // This is not the correct syntax
?>
```

What is the correct syntax for Objective array?

Comment: `$arr1->{$arr2[1]};`

Comment: `Objective array` Do you mean an array of Objects?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. Sorry for my wrong sentence.

Comment: @u_mulder $arr[2] is also an array of objects

Comment: `$arr1->{$arr2[0]->prop};`

Comment: @u_mulder that worked. Thank You so much!